# Display array of JavaScript objects

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Just a quick short example of what I'm trying to do:

```
Salamander = {
    Name: getName(),
    SvLength: getSvLength(),
    TotLength: getTotLength()
};

aSal.push(Salamander);
```

What would be the best way to display a variable number of Salamanders' data on the screen? There can be an indiscriminate number of them in the array.

What would the HTML markup even look like for something like this? And how would I script it to be filled by the data?

Comment: A table with three columns? It's totally up to you...

Comment: But wouldn't that not work? Would I have to create a whole new <tr> for each item? I'm just confused as to how to even make it with a table.

Comment: @Brendan You leave that up to the templating engine (Handlebars & co.). The idea is to have the templating engine generate a HTML source code string, end then you just append that HTML string to the page (via jQuery).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the HTML dynamically if you don't know the number of elements or anything else for that matter.

Do something like this, how you do your markup us up to you, but you get the point:

```
var output;

$.each(aSal, function(index, item) {
    output += '<ul class="salamander_wrapper">';
    output += '<li class="name">'+this.Name+'</li>';
    output += '<li class="length">'+this.SvLength+'</li>';
    output += '<li class="tot_length">'+this.TotLength+'</li>';
    output += '</ul>';
});

$(output).appendTo('body');
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/8jZQC/1/)

Comment: Yes it would, just an example really, but I'll change it anyway ? I've even added a fiddle!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have a collection of Salamander objects, and you want to find the index of a salamander object for a specific object.

You could use a for loop to loop to the item with a specific property:

```
function getIndexForName(name) {
    for(var i = 0; i < aSal.length; i++) {
        if(aSal[i].Name == name) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1; // not found
}
```

To display the entire array in a table, you could loop through the for loop and populate a table td cell by first cloning an HTML template on your page and then adding data to it dynamically using jQuery. The advantage of this technique is you can perform this action without needing to generate HTML on the server side.

```
<table id="salamanders">
    <tr>
        <th>Index</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>SvLength</th>
        <th>TotLength</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item">
         <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>

var tr = $('#salamanders').find("tr:last").clone();
var td = $('#salamanders').find("td").clone();


$('#salamanders').find("td").remove();
$('#salamanders').find("tr:last").remove();

for(var i = 0; i < aSal.length; i++) {
    // clone the tr element from earlier and insert into the table.
    $('#salamanders').append(tr.clone());

    // insert the index
    $('#salamanders').find("tr:last").append(td.clone());
    $('#salamanders').find("td:last").innerHTML = i;

    // insert the name
    $('#salamanders').find("tr:last").append(td.clone());
    $('#salamanders').find("td:last").innerHTML = aSal[i].Name;

    // insert SvLength
    $('#salamanders').find("tr:last").append(td.clone());
    $('#salamanders').find("td:last").innerHTML = aSal[i].SvLength;

    // insert TotLength
    $('#salamanders').find("tr:last").append(td.clone());
    $('#salamanders').find("td:last").innerHTML = aSal[i].TotLength;       
}
```

This should definitely help get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/8EkQ5/

There are slicker ways to do this using, for example, javascript templating.  But this seems adequate for your circumstances.

Snippet here:

```
var tableHtml = "<table border='1'>";
for (var i = 0; i < rando; i++) {
   tableHtml += "<tr><td>"+newArray[i]+"</td></tr>";
}
tableHtml += "</table>";

document.getElementById("tableholder").innerHTML = tableHtml;
```